# AJAX live insert delete search, shows items 2 times

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

When i insert an item it is shown on the list 2 times, but on mysql table it is registered just one time. It started when i started using sessions. Thank you in advance.

index.php

```
<html>  
  <head>  
       <title>Live Table Data Edit</title>  
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  </head>  
  <body>  
       <div class="container">  
            <br />  
            <br />  
            <br />  
            <div class="table-responsive">  
                 <h3 align="center">Lista articulos prestados</h3><br />  
                 <div id="live_data"></div>                 
            </div>  
       </div>  
  </body>  
 </html>  
<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
  function fetch_data()  
  {  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"select.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            success:function(data){  
                 $('#live_data').html(data);  
            }  
       });  
  }  
  fetch_data();  
  $(document).on('click', '#btn_add', function(){  
       var Articulo = $('#Articulo').text();  
       var fecha = $('#fecha').text(); 
       var emailpresta = $('#emailpresta').text();
       var emailrecibe = $('#emailrecibe').text(); 
       if(Articulo == '')  
       {  
            alert("Ingresa Articulo");  
            return false;  
       }  
       if(fecha == '')  
       {  
            alert("Ingresa Fecha");  
            return false;  
       }  
       if(emailpresta == '')  
       {  
            alert("Ingresa tu email");  
            return false;  
       }  
       if(emailrecibe == '')  
       {  
            alert("Ingresa email tercero");  
            return false;  
       }  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"insert.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{Articulo:Articulo, fecha:fecha, emailpresta:emailpresta,     emailrecibe:emailrecibe },  
            dataType:"text",  
            success:function(data)  
            {  
                 alert(data);  
                 fetch_data();  
            }  
       })  
  });     
  $(document).on('click', '.btn_delete', function(){  
       var id=$(this).data("id3");  
       if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))  
       {  
            $.ajax({  
                 url:"delete.php",  
                 method:"POST",  
                 data:{id:id},  
                 dataType:"text",  
                 success:function(data){  
                      alert(data);  
                      fetch_data();  
                 }  
            });  
       }  
  });  
 });  
 </script>
```

select.php

```
<?php  
session_start();

 $check_usuario = $_SESSION['email'];
 $connect = mysqli_connect("######", "######", "", "############");  
 $output = '';  
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM articulos INNER JOIN usuarios WHERE     emailpresta='".$check_usuario."'";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
 $output .= '  
  <div class="table-responsive">  
       <table class="table table-bordered">  
            <tr>  
                 <th width="10%">Id</th>  
                 <th width="40%">Articulo</th>  
                 <th width="40%">Fecha(Formato: AAAA-MM-DD)</th>  
                 <th width="40%">Email-presta</th>
                 <th width="40%">Email-recibe</th>    
                 <th width="10%">Borrar</th>  
            </tr>';  
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
 {  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
  {  
       $output .= '  
            <tr>  
                 <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>  
                 <td class="Articulo" data-id1="'.$row["id"].'"   contenteditable>'.$row["Articulo"].'</td>  
                 <td class="fecha" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["fecha"].'</td>  
                 <td class="emailpresta" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["emailpresta"].'</td> 
                 <td class="emailrecibe" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["emailrecibe"].'</td> 
                 <td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" data-   id3="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete">x</button></td>  
            </tr>  
       ';  
  }  
  $output .= '  
       <tr>  
            <td></td>  
            <td id="Articulo" contenteditable></td>  
            <td id="fecha" contenteditable></td>  
            <td id="emailpresta" contenteditable></td> 
            <td id="emailrecibe" contenteditable></td> 
            <td><button type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add" class="btn    btn-xs btn-success">+</button></td>  
       </tr>  
    ';  
 }  
 else  
 {  
  $output .= '<tr>  
                      <td></td>
                      <td id="Articulo" contenteditable></td>  
                      <td id="fecha" contenteditable></td>  
                      <td id="emailpresta" contenteditable></td> 
                      <td id="emailrecibe" contenteditable></td> 
                      <td><button type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add"     class="btn btn-xs btn-success">+</button></td>  
                 </tr>';  
 }  
 $output .= '</table>  
  </div>';  
 echo $output;  
 ?>
```

insert.php

```
<?php  
  session_start();
  $connect = mysqli_connect("############", "############", "", "############");  
 $sql = "INSERT INTO articulos(Articulo, fecha, emailpresta, emailrecibe)     VALUES('".$_POST["Articulo"]."', '".$_POST["fecha"]."'
    , '".$_POST["emailpresta"]."', '".$_POST["emailrecibe"]."')";  
 if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql))  
 {  
  echo 'Data Inserted';  
 }  
 ?>
```

delete.php

```
  <?php  
  session_start();
  $connect = mysqli_connect("############", "############", "", "############");  
  $sql = "DELETE FROM articulos WHERE id = '".$_POST["id"]."'";  
  if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql))  
  {  
   echo 'Data Deleted';  
  }  
  ?>
```

Comment: When you get help with your problem, don't just leave or soon people will stop helping you. You haven't selected an answer for any of the questions you've posted, including this one. Is my reply not helpful?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely with you MySQL query.  What shows up on screen when you execute the following:

```
//session_start();  <-- do not start session
$email = '......'; <-- use an email from the DB with data available
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articulos INNER JOIN usuarios 
                  WHERE emailpresta='$email'";
$connect = mysqli_connect(...);
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

$data = mysqli_fetch_all($result));
print_r($data);
```

Do you see duplicate rows?  If so, you'll need to work on your SQL query. Specifically, you don't tell the database how to join the `articulos` and `usarios` tables. Instead of

```
SELECT * from articulos INNER JOIN usarios WHERE emailpresta='$email'
```

You probably need something like:

```
SELECT * from articulos INNER JOIN usarios ON articulos.userID=usarios.ID
                                   WHERE usarios.emailpresta='$email'
```

Instead of `articulos.userID` and `usarios.ID`, use the fields in the two tables that match up. You can learn a bit about INNER JOIN [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx)

**Side note**

I noticed that you plug `$_SESSION['email']` directly into your DB query. If this is a value that you received from the user, you run a huge risk of [SQL injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection_attack), a way for anyone to execute any query (including extracting, modifying or deleting your DB records) using specially crafted inputs.  Look into using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead. Even if the contents of `$_SESSION['email']` are safe, running raw queries is a risky habit anywhere you take input from the user.